# 80's barbarian movie with female lead, evil scientist, pool of acid

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was the late 80's and my friends and I were having a "bad movie" night with a barbarian theme. The Conan movies were way too high-budget to be eligible.

The lead character was a female barbarian who had been captured (don't remember how) by an evil/mad scientist. In the scene I remember most vividly, he had her strapped to a table spread-eagle by her wrists and ankles, with the table tilted to the not-quite-vertical. He walked up to her and tried to erm... Okay, I'm not sure what the family-friendliness requirement is here, so I'll be a little circumspect. He got overly friendly with her, but as soon as he made contact she captured him with her barbarian-strong vaginal muscles, then executed a pelvic thrust which put him so off balance that he tumbled backward into the conveniently placed pool of acid and died.

Comment: If you've never seen Red Sonja, it's another interesting 80s "female barb" movie.  Arnold takes the supporting role in this film.

Comment: @Eckert - 'Barbarian Queen' is to 'Red Sonja' as 'Star Crash' is to 'Star Wars'. Both are ostensibly about the same thing, but one is sh*t and the other isn't.

Comment: I can’t find a good, concise reference, but the policies seem to be: (1) Absolutely no profanity (“four-letter words”) in question titles. (2) Try to minimize profanity in question bodies. The main exception is on the language-related sites, where you are allowed to ask questions like “What does \***\* mean?” (but only in the body of the question, not the title). (3) Be nice. Don’t say anything for shock value, or to be offensive. (4) Beyond that, say what you need to say to ask your question or present your answer (or comment).

Comment: Sounds like the Evil Overlord list needs another entry.

Comment: @davidbak - Rules #5 (no gloating) and #87 (no uncovered vats of chemicals) are more than sufficient to have covered this incident.

Comment: Thanks @PeregrineRook. I guess that means I could edit the question to be more straightforward, but it does no harm as it is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is "[Barbarian Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarian_Queen)", a 1985 American-Argentine fantasy film starring Lana Clarkson and produced by Roger Corman.

> **The torturer later rapes Amethea, but she uses her feminine strength
>   to squeeze his manhood painfully during the assault, forcing him to
>   release her from the rack, whereupon Amethea hurls him into a pool of
>   acid and escapes the dungeon.** Finding Estrild, the two women flee the
>   castle and regroup with the rebels, who agree to help in the planned
>   overthrow of Arrakur's forces led by Argan during the gladatorial
>   games. Amethea and the rebels join with the gladiators in the attack.
>   Amethea fights Arrakur in one-on-one combat during the melee, but is
>   defeated and disarmed by him. Before Arrakur can deliver the killing
>   blow, however, Taramis stabs him in the back, killing him. Amethea and
>   Argan are reunited and celebrate the liberation of the city from
>   Arrakur's tyranny

**Warning. NSFW content in the link below.**

**No. Seriously. Don't look at it.**

> The scene in question can be seen [here](https://ok.ru/video/302429833857) at timecode 00:49:07.

Comment: I remember screaming with laughter at this scene. I guess the pelvic thrust came in when my friends started riffing on it.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam So I guess you could say that it was the pelvic thrust that really drove you insane?